# How to create fade-in fade-out image slide show in wp7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

My question is "How to create fade-in fade-out image slide show in wp7?". I am able to make normal slideshow from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42888/Silverlight-3-Slideshow) but I want an animated slideshow. I am using C#.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using Expression Blend to do this. It automates much of the animation process for you.

**This should get you started.**

http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/jennmar/Animation-Using-Expression-Blend-Part-1-How-to-create-an-animation